# Find the current financial Quarter first date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have read many posts here but couldn't get what I wanted. I am currently new to Javascript and don't know how to get the first `Date` of the current quarter in `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With moment 1.7.0+ it is just

```
moment().startOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 5):

Getting the date in JavaScript, using moment.js to format:

```
var qtrDate = (function () {
    var d = new Date(),
        m = d.getMonth() - d.getMonth() % 3;
    return moment(new Date(d.getFullYear(), m, 1)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
}());
```

or

```
function getQuarterFirstDay (d) {
    var m = d.getMonth() - d.getMonth() % 3;
    return moment(new Date(d.getFullYear(), m, 1)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
}
var d = getQuarterFirstDay(new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure javascript solution:

```js
var currentMonth=(new Date()).getMonth()
var yyyy = (new Date()).getFullYear()
var start = (Math.floor(currentMonth/3)*3)+1;
end= start+3;
startDate=new Date(start+'-01-'+ yyyy);
endDate= end>12?new Date('01-01-'+ (yyyy+1)):new Date(end+'-01-'+ (yyyy));
endDate=new Date((endDate.getTime())-1)
    
console.log('startDate =', startDate,'endDate =', endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.However i already got the solution and i used the code below. Haven't tested the above code .

```
    var m = Math.floor(parseInt(month) / 3);
    var month = m * 3;
    if(month == 0){ 
    month=1;
    } 
    fromDate = "0" + month + "/" + "01/" + moment(today).format("YYYY");
    toDate = moment(today).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Comment: Please note that for months < 3 (in your `parseInt`), `fromDate` will result in `'00/01/2014'`. In my answer, I use modulus to get the difference between the current month and the beginning of the quarter. This works out of box since `getMonth` returns a 0-indexed  month (0-11).